# Setting max idle time of an hazelcast map at run time

Tags: java, hazelcast

I want to set the max idle time of an hazelcast map at run time.
I know the configuration entry to achieve this is `mapConfig.setMaxIdleSeconds(timeInSec);`

Is there any way I can set the idle time of an IMap at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

By using hazelcast management center, see: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#managing-maps
It is free up to two nodes.

It uses internal classes to update map config, so there's no supported programmatic way of doing this yet.